# Evercookie for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm finding a solution to detect cheaters creating many accounts at my website.

I have found permanent cross-browser cookies: http://samy.pl/evercookie/
But it written on JS, and I need something to use in rails controller. Is there any gem or plugin like evercookie?

Comment: What kind of site is it? You could do a user-verification with, e.g. a Facebook login.

Comment: I want to add that this is not the solution to your problem. Captchas are what you're looking for if you're really paranoid, but hidden fields (empty by default, fake if filled by automatic scripts) will probably be enough for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I was searching for Evercookie solution for Rails, didn't find and wrote a gem 'evercookie'. You can [try it](https://rubygems.org/gems/evercookie). 
Documentation is available on [github](https://github.com/daddyz/evercookie)

Answer (score 3):

#### Email token (Devise, Sorcery)

Can you send an email to a new user?

A simple solution that many websites use is sending the user an email with a security token. A good Rails gem for this is Devise, and another is Sorcery which makes it simple to build your own custom authentication.

#### Third-party sign in (OmniAuth, OpenId, Facebook Connect, Twitter, etc.)

Can you authenticate the user with a third-party service?

The OmniAuth gem can connect to many third-party services and let the user authenticate using an existing account on Google, Yahoo, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, and open services including LDAP and Shibboleth.

The OpenId gem works well with Google, Yahoo, and many other large providers; you can also use OpenId within OmniAuth.

In all these cases you would track the sending, so that a user can't apply again too quickly by using the same phone number, postal address, credit card, etc.

#### Phone Message (Twilio)

Can you send your user a text message?

The Twilio gem enables sending text messages to phone numbers. The concept is that your 
app sends them a text message with a verification code.

#### Snail mail (postalmethods)

The postalmethods gem lets you send real, physical postcards in the postal mail. You can send a postcard with a verification code. This may take a few days, so some sites use this in conjunction with a "probationary period" for new users where they are somewhat sandboxed from causing any trouble. (for example, they can read info, but not post info).

#### Credit card (BrainTree)

Related ideas are to have the user send you something that requires a credit card, such as using a payment gateway like BrainTree or ActiveMerchant.

You can verify the card is open and valid without charging any money to it. Or you could require a tiny minimum payment, such as requiring the user to send you one dollar via PayPal, Google Payments, Amazon Dev Pay, etc.

Credit card numbers have internal structure (like a checksum) so you could verify that the number is the right format and checksum. A simple script is flame.org

#### Image Captchas (recaptcha)

To block bots, captchas such as Ruby recaptcha work very well.

Ruby has other captcha solutions and any of these are likely fine.

#### Karma (hypothes.is)

This isn't a gem, but it's a concept. Give new users limited privileges, such as read-only access. Let users earn new privileges by being a member for a certain amount of time, or by contributing content, or by connecting with friends and peers within your site, etc.

This is how sites like StackOverflow work, and there's a lot of good information about these approaches at http://hypothes.is

#### Combos

The most powerful approach is combinations of these techniques.

Perhaps give a new user some basic capabilities, such as reading information, and then let him earn new capabilities by doing one or more of the authentications above. This is how Google and Facebook add some features: you can sign up easily, then authenticate other emails, then authenticate your phone number, then authenticate your postal address.

Comment: I already use it. If somebody get banned, he just create another account. They are users, not bots.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no Rail drop-in solution and it wouldn't make much sense.

> evercookie is written in JavaScript and additionally uses a SWF (Flash) object for the Local Shared Objects and PHPs for the server-side generation of cached PNGs and ETags.

Almost all of the Evercookie techniques rely on special Javascript APIs to the browser, so there's no way of porting them to a server-side technology (except for the small PHP part).

A gem might make integration and updates easier, but it would still be Javascript for the client side.

Please consider the ethical implications of Evercookie. It is a proof of concept, not a tool to be widely used, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to roll out your own solution, a good starting point (with cookies) would be:

```
def create
  if cookies[:xyz]
    render :text => 'cheater!'
  else
    # save the user first (you may need to display the form again), and then set the cookie
    cookies[:xyz] = { :value => "1", :expires => 1.day.from_now }
   end
end
```

EDIT: this is not comparable to evercookie, just a simple alternative.

EDIT 2: I already said that captchas are what the author should probably use, so am I being downvoted for showing what a starting point would be if he still wants to use cookies?

Comment: I know about simple cookies, but user is able to delete it or change browser.

Comment: Users who want to cheat the system will always find a way. Use captchas.

Comment: Don't try to roll your own solutions for security. Use captchas.